# BouncyCastle Library in ColdFusion 10

Tags: java, coldfusion, bouncycastle, coldfusion-10

I've been trying to get RSA Private Key Encryption working in ColdFusion 10 and installed the BouncyCastle library since it supports the encryption mode that my application requires.  Trying to load the library with JavaLoader resulted in errors ("Class is on the bootclasspath" and "JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC") so I had to install it statically...

Copy the jar to `%CF_ROOT%/jre/lib/ext/` and add the following to `%CF_ROOT%/jre/lib/security/java.security`:

```
security.provider.<N>=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Without realizing it at the time, I had also removed the library from the code but statements that use the library still worked:

```
var privateKey = createObject("java", "org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader").init(
    createObject("java", "java.io.FileReader").init(LOCAL.privateKeyPath)
).readPemObject().getContent();
```

So either I permanently installed BouncyCastle in my ColdFusion install, or it comes included in ColdFusion.  I've since removed the static provider installation and encryption using the "BC" provider continues to work without modification.  If BouncyCastle is bundled with CF then that's great, but on another machine running an equally updated version of ColdFusion (CF10 update 13), the createObject statement is failing because it can't find the PemReader class.  I've googled my eyes bloody and cannot find any documentation on BouncyCastle being included in any version of CF - except for a clause about BouncyCastle in the CF10 EULA.

The question is this: Is BouncyCastle included in CF10 and if so, how do I make sure it's enabled?

Comment: I've found that I have a BouncyCastle library installed in coldfusion: '%CF_ROOT%/cfusion/lib/bcprov-jdk14-139.jar'.  Jars in this directory are loaded through the coldfusion.libPath in the JVM arguments.  I didn't put that jar there and it already existed on the machine that still doesn't work so the question is still the same.

Comment: (Edit) *since removed the static provider installation* What exactly did you remove? The security file, BC jar or both? If you did not remove **all** versions of the jar from the class path, and restart CF, the new jar would still be loaded and accessible. Likely that is why you could still reference the newer PemReader class on the one server. You can determine the source jar of an object using [this old tip](http://web.archive.org/web/20110625025121/http://bpurcell.org/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=982) (courtesy of web.archive.org)

Comment: I undid the changes that I made to install the provider.  I deleted the jar from %CF_ROOT%/jre/lib/ext/ and removed the line referenced above from %CF_ROOT%/jre/lib/security/java.security

Answer (score 2):

While I'm still unclear why two machines with the same version of CF with the same version of the same java package would have a discrepancy in the classes included in that package, I did find a workaround.

The `org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader` class in the BouncyCastle Provider package is a replacement for the deprecated `org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader` class in the BouncyCastle PKIX/OpenSSL package.  Since CF10 comes with a relatively old version of BC (v1.39-jdk1.4), it still includes the deprecated class.  Replacing the code above with the following code corrected the issue...

```
var privateKeyFile = createObject("java", "java.io.FileReader").init("myPrivateKey.pem");
var privateKey = createObject("java", "org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader").init( privateKeyFile ).readObject().getPrivate().getEncoded();
privateKeyFile.close();
```

It also has the benefit of explicitly closing the file (though that was always possible).

Note: The machines that had the earlier issue also weren't loading the BouncyCastle security provider.  It seems to be available on every machine, but not always loaded so I had to explicitly load it if it wasn't already:

```
var securityProviders = createObject("java", "java.security.Security").getProviders();
var providerInstalled = false;
for( var provider IN securityProviders ){
    if( provider.getName() eq "BC" ){
        providerInstalled = true;
        break;
    }
}
if( not providerInstalled )
    createObject("java", "java.security.Security")
        .addProvider( createObject("java", "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider").init() );
```

Comment: As you say, CF does ship with an older version of BC. If you are positive the machines are running the exact same version, then it is not a discrepancy. One machine must still have the newer version of the BC jar *in the class path*. The other does not. That is why you can access the newer class on one machine, but not the other.

Comment: I checked the JVM options in the CF Admin on both machines and they were the same.  I had deleted the jar that I installed earlier and restarted CF a few times so I don't know how it would have kept a reference to it.  Actually it won't let you delete the file without first stopping CF.

Comment: Did you copy the jar into any other folders during testing or is it referenced in your application settings ie THIS.javaSettings? The behavior you are describing almost certainly indicates there is a newer version in the class path of one machine/application but not the other. I am not near a CF install, but IIRC the Admin screen does not list everything in the entire *JVM* class path. What happened when you used [the earlier link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027957/bouncycastle-library-in-coldfusion-10?noredirect=1#comment39002768_25027957) to determine the source jar of the class?

Comment: I only installed the jar in one place and then deleted it from there.  I didn't update the JVM classpath, just looked at it.  The code ran on other machines that never installed the jar at all - I had committed the code and not everyone that pulled the latest had issues.  The jar was outside the repository so it was never committed.  I haven't had time to check the source of the class.  I'll test it later today and report back.

Comment: What I meant was the Admin screen may not list every place searched for classes/jars. *The code ran on other machines that never installed the jar at all* Well, something is different. Are you positive it is the newer class, not the older one? If they are all running the same version of CF as you say, and that class is not present in the core jar (I have not tested this), then a different version of the jar must be in the *JVM* class path somewhere - or referenced in application jar settings. Checking the source jar for the loaded class should tell us more.